# What’s the plural of “Valentine’s”

Tags: grammatical-number, apostrophe

If I want to form the plural of “Valentine’s” as a short form of “Saint Valentine’s Day” – where do I put the apostrophe(s)? Is it possible at all?

I believe that *Valentines’*, although the normal plural form of a genitive ending in “s”, would be wrong here since that would mean “the day of the people who are called Valentine”. So what’s right? *Valentine’s’ ?*

Here’s an example of where I’d use this form:

> She had spent so many Valentine’s’ alone that she now loathed the very mention of this day.

– Of course I could simply write it out … but where’s the fun in that?

Comment: If you can’t bring yourself to write “so many Valentine’s days”, just say “so many Valentines”.  Anything else will look terrible.

Comment: I think it would be pretty unusual to use *Valentines* to mean the actual day[s] - the stand-alone form normally refers to *Valentine **cards***. But if OP wants to "discard" both words *("card" and "day")*, it seems to me there's nothing left to apostrophise anyway, so multiple Valentine's Days would have to be **Valentines**, just as they would be if they were multiple cards.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think you’re confusing that: the *card* is simply called a “Valentine” (as is the person you’d send it to). As for the rest of the comment: why not make it an answer? (And if you think the short form is too uncommon, what about “New Year’s”?)

Comment: @Konrad: I don't *think* I'm confusing anything. On the odd occasions when the single word is used to refer to the day itself it would obviously be *"I didn't get many cards this Valentine's"*, but if you wanted to "pluralise" the last word the only credible option is to simply discard the apostrophe. I didn't post it as an answer because to be honest I think the question is both General Reference *and* Too Localised.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Wait, “too localised” is a legitimate close reason here on English.SE? Oh, there go all the [single-word-request]s.

Comment: @Konrad: Firstly, I *didn't* closevote. Secondly, I also think it's General Reference that you can't add another **s** (apostrophised or not) to a word already ending in **'s** that's being used as a singular noun. For example, I can imagine a nurse saying *"We have several Parkinsons on the ward"*. I've no idea if they're in the habit of dropping the word "patients/cases/sufferers" in such contexts, but if they *do*, they'd have no choice but to also drop the apostrophe, as per tchrist's first comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, “Valentine’s” is less common than “Valentine’s Day” — usually only the “St.” is dropped<sup>1</sup> — so I think the usual phrasing would be:

> She had spent so many Valentine’s Days alone that she now loathed the very mention of this day.

Another option, if you really want to use “Valentine’s” alone (without “Day”), is to treat it as a proper noun, and write:

> She had spent Valentine’s alone so many times that she now loathed the very mention of this day.

(Compare “She had spent Christmas alone so many times […]”.)

---

1. For example, compare [the Google Books hits for "from Valentine's to"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22from+Valentine%27s+to%22&tbm=bks) to [those for "from Valentine's Day to"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22from+Valentine%27s+Day+to%22&tbm=bks).

Comment: I’ve always thought that Americans, or at least Hallmark, drop the “Saint” part because they don’t wish to appear Catholic.

Comment: The Google links actually show a relation of 1:3 in frequency, not too big a difference – but I’m not sure how much we can read into that anyway. I quite like the answer.

Comment: @tchrist: That may be why people started dropping it -- I really don't know -- but nowadays the reason that people continue to drop it is, simply, that everyone drops it. Today, including the "Saint" doesn't make one sound Catholic, it makes one sound formal, or strange. It would be like referring to Halloween as "All Hallows' Eve" rather than "Halloween".

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Oops, I messed up the links. I meant to link to Google *Books*, which has few enough examples that you can compare them more meaningfully. I'll fix that.

Comment: I'm afraid I have to downvote this one, because it simply sidesteps OP's question by suggesting a rephrasing that avoids referencing *"Valentine's Days"* as a "single-word plural". It's perfectly possible to say *"She had spent so many Christmases alone..."*, for example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Is that a site policy? On Stack Overflow (where I spend more time than here), it's considered perfectly O.K. to post a workaround, the idea being that the *main* goal is to solve the OP's problem. (An answer that answers the question directly is better, of course, when one exists.) Does ELU not take that view?

Comment: @ruakh Okay, but then I’d argue that dropping “Day” here would be clearly not written English so its underrepresentation in books is to be expected.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: That's certainly possible.

Comment: @ruakh: I don't think there's any "site policy" in this particular respect. And I certainly wouldn't normally downvote an answer just because it was a "workaround". My comment was meant to imply that I downvoted this one with regret, because I think it's a perfectly good way of avoiding the issue. But it seems to me OP already knows he has that option - he's very specifically asking whether/how he could pluralise **Valentine's** (which in his context can only be seen as a ***singular** noun*).

Comment: I often hear people refer to the holiday as simply "Valentine's", like the OP's example. I'm struggling to think of other holidays where we do this for comparison. I've never heard someone say, "We get off for Veterans'" rather than "... for Veterans' Day". Perhaps because it would sound like you were talking about the class of people, verterans. Whereas it's not liking that a reference to "Valentine's" would make most people think of the person rather than the holiday in most contexts.

Comment: @tchrist RE "saint", I've always assumed that people just left it off because they were lazy. I wouldn't insist on calling Queen Victoria's Birthday simply Victoria's Birthday on the grounds that, as an American, she is not my queen, but I certainly might drop the "queen" part just to make it shorter. But I can't presume what goes on in other people's heads.

Answer (score 0):

In the expression, Saint Valentine's Day, "day" is the noun that is being discussed. Therefore that is the word that is pluralized. I'm not going to get into the whole "dropping the Saint" argument since that isn't anything to do with the OP's question.

Answer (score -1):

It should be St. Valentines' Days according to the rules I was taught at school - basically it should read Valentines's but the two consecutive  S  get condensed.

Comment: I don’t think this is correct: if you don’t drop the “Day” then the “Valentine’s” part doesn’t get modified at all by pluralising the expression — only “Day” does. So I’m pretty sure it’s “Valentine’s Days”, not “Valentines’ Days”. Compare: “David’s boot”→“David’s boots”, *not* “Davids’ boots”.